# Why isn't my !include directive working in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am experimenting with option files in MySQL.  I have a `~/.my.cnf` file which includes only the following:

```
!include /Users/myself/Workspace/project_time/mysql/foo.cnf

[client]
i_am_a_dummy
```

And I have a file `/Users/myself/Workspace/project_time/mysql/foo.cnf` which includes only the following:

```
[mysqld]
skip_column_names
```

I have newlines at the end of each file.

I also have a database, `new_database`, which includes a table `t1`.

I run MySQL with the command `mysql -uroot -p new_database;` and type in my password at the prompt, after which I see the MySQL prompt.  When I type `select * from t1;` at the prompt, I would expect to see the output without headers, like so:

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+------+------+
| 2001 | 1    | 1    |
| 2001 | 1    | 20   |
| 2001 | 1    | 30   |
| 2001 | 2    | 2    |
| 2001 | 2    | 23   |
| 2001 | 2    | 23   |
+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Unfortunately, instead I see the following:

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+-------+------+
| year | month | day  |
+------+-------+------+
| 2001 |     1 |    1 |
| 2001 |     1 |   20 |
| 2001 |     1 |   30 |
| 2001 |     2 |    2 |
| 2001 |     2 |   23 |
| 2001 |     2 |   23 |
+------+-------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have already tried to use `[client]` as the option group in `foo.cnf` instead of `[mysqld]`, but that did not work.

When I add `skip_column_names` directly to `~/.my.cnf` (just below `i_am_a_dummy`), it works as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Settings for the _server_ go under `[mysqld]`.  Settings for the commandline `mysql` need to be under `[mysql]` or `[client]`.  (Put them under both.)

Answer (score 0):

When I created `foo.cnf`, I set the permissions to `777`.  Apparently world-writable config files are ignored:

```
~/Workspace/project_time/mysql ()  $ mysql --print-defaults -uroot -p<secret> new_database;
mysql: [Warning] World-writable config file '/Users/myself/Workspace/project_time/mysql/foo.cnf' is ignored.
mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--i_am_a_dummy -uroot -p<secret> new_database
```

When I reset the permissions for `foo.cnf` to `755` and re-run the command, I get the following:

```
~/Workspace/project_time/mysql ()  $ chmod 755 foo.cnf 
~/Workspace/project_time/mysql ()  $ mysql --print-defaults -uroot -p<secret> new_database;
mysql would have been started with the following arguments:
--skip_column_names --i_am_a_dummy -uroot -p<secret> new_database
```

And when I invoke the aforementioned `SELECT` statement in the CLI, it appears as expected:

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+------+------+
| 2001 | 1    | 1    |
| 2001 | 1    | 20   |
| 2001 | 1    | 30   |
| 2001 | 2    | 2    |
| 2001 | 2    | 23   |
| 2001 | 2    | 23   |
+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT: The warning is actually printed out even when not passing the `--print-defaults` flag, I just didn't notice it among the other output in the CLI.  Since `--print-defaults` results in much less output on start-up, the warning was easier to notice.